# Is there an efficient busy waiting method in kernel?

Tags: process, operating-system, sleep, wakeup, busy-waiting

Suppose a process is waiting for a lock held by some other process. Either it spinlocks (Busy waits) or it goes to sleep, to be woken up when the lock is released. If the waiting time is too much, it is better to sleep, since too much resources will be hogged. If the waiting time is short, the spinlocking is preferred, to avoid the overhead from sleeping and waking. Now, usually the process itself takes the decision whether to spinlock or sleep. But is there a way to make this decision from the OS?

So, the question is, is there a technique for the OS to know when a process is awaiting a lock, and if so, any efficient technique using which the OS itself decides (from how long the waiting time might be for the lock to be released) whether to allow the process to busy-wait, or to sleep the process ?

Comment: 'from how long the waiting time might be' - the OS has no way of knowing.  It's common to spin for a short period to cover the common 'quick' cases, eg. a thread dequeing a pointer, and then give up and block the thread.  Obviously, such schemes are ineffective on the, (increasingly rare), single-core systems.

Comment: @MartinJames Of course, it is impossible to know for sure, but is there a good way for the OS to make a good estimate (like when the time is estimated for pre-emptive job scheduling) and take one of the choices accordingly?

Comment: There is no time for guesstimating.  Some thread calls a for a lock that may, or may not, be required for some tens of nanoseconds or much more.  The OS has no clue what is happening inside the multithreaded server with arrays of buffer pools, and should not waste cycles on guesses that would be likely wrong.  'like when the time is estimated for pre-emptive job scheduling'...... I am not sure what kind of system that is.  If it's batch processing, I have not used such a system since DEC VAX, (cretaceous computing:)